# Changing the values in a scala map

Tags: scala

I have a Scala `Map` like this:

```
Map("a"->"Null", "b"->"12", "c"->"23", "d"->"", "e"->"apple", "f"->"pear", "g"->"banana", "h"->null)
```

Now, I want to replace the values of keys that contains (`a`, `d`, `h`) with 0.0, which should result in a map like this:

```
Map("a"->"0.0", "b"->"12", "c"->"23", "d"->"0.0", "e"->"apple", "f"->"pear", "g"->"banana", "h"->"0.0")
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
val data = Map("a"->"Null", "b"->"12", "c"->"23", "d"->"", "e"->"apple", "f"->"pear", "g"->"banana", "h"->null)

val replaced = data.map {
  case (k@("a"|"d"|"h"), v) => (k, "0.0")
  case x => x
}
```

(*Edited the above to use Dima's more succinct syntax.*)

If your intent is to replace null or null-like values with "0.0", you could do this:

```
val replaced = data.map {
  case (k, v) if (isNull(v)) => (k, "0.0")
  case x => x
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of `isNull` to you.

Comment: A bit shorter: `case (k@("a"|"d"|"h"), v) => k -> "0.0"; case x => x`

Comment: Would be a bit shorter again, if instead of `isNull`, you do `object Null { def unapply(s: Any) = Option(s).filterNot(s == "" || s == "Null").isEmpty }`, and then you can write `case (k, Null(v)) => k -> "0.0"`

Comment: Here is useless to use map method, cause mapValues is enough:
data.mapValues{ 
  case ("Null" | "" | null) => "0.0" 
  case v => v
}

Comment: Thanks for all.Your answer will make all the key corresponding value that contains("Null",null,"") converted to 0.0 .But I just want some specific key corresponding to the value that contains("Null",null,"") converted to 0.0 .
In this example,I only want to the key("a","b","c","d","h") corresponding to the value that contains("Null",null,"") converted to 0.0 .The other does not change like the key is e,f,g(Even if they contain "Null",null,"") . Thanks